# Need to extract specific text from a column on excel using either Alteryx or Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, alteryx

I have a column that contains a specific set of text that I need to be retained and the rest removed or moved to another column. Unfortunately, I am not able to use normal text-to-column due to the variation of the text arrangement.

For example, I need the word Issue and the id associated with it to be separated. I am struggling to figure out a way to do this with the variation of the arrangement of the text I need.

[image]

If someone can help me find a  solution using Alteryx would be much appreciated, if not Pandas would also work.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with Pattern to extract specific text from the data frame [Pandas]

```
df['After']=df['Before'].str.extract(pat='(ISSUE \d+|issue \d+)',expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For an Alteryx-only solution, the easiest way would be an Alteryx Formula using [REGEX_Replace](https://help.alteryx.com/20213/designer/string-functions#regex_replace):

```
REGEX_Replace([Before],".*(issue \d+).*","?1",1)
```

If you don't like RegEx, basic string manipulations can do it also: basically it's a Substring...

```
Substring([Before], *starting index*, *length*)
```

The *starting index* is easy: it's just `FindString([Before],"ISSUE")`

The *length* isn't too hard either: it's the index (using `FindString` again) of the first comma in the substring that starts with "ISSUE": `SubString([Before],FindString([Before],"ISSUE"))`

Combining all that and spreading it out a bit:

```
Substring(
  [Before],
  FindString([Before],"ISSUE"),
  FindString(
    SubString(
      [Before],
      FindString([Before],"ISSUE")
    ),","
  )
)
```